# I have unwanted space above my nav bar list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

The space above my list items appears to be where the bullets used to be, and I'd rather not use a negative margin to move my text.  Is there a way to get rid of this space?

Heres the HTML:

```
        <div class="header">
            <div id="pagetitle">
                <p class="title">TEST</p>
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl"><br>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><br>ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><br>WORK</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="om.html">ODD MACHINE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="personal.html">PERSONAL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><br>CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 95%;
    min-width: 800px;
    border-right: solid thick;
    border-left: solid thick;
}

#gradientbg
{
    max-width: 95%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,136,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,87,21,0) 84%, rgba(255,79,25,0.88) 98%, rgba(255,79,25,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,136,0,0)), color-stop(84%,rgba(255,87,21,0)), color-stop(98%,rgba(255,79,25,0.88)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,79,25,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,87,21,0) 84%,rgba(255,79,25,0.88) 98%,rgba(255,79,25,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,87,21,0) 84%,rgba(255,79,25,0.88) 98%,rgba(255,79,25,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,87,21,0) 84%,rgba(255,79,25,0.88) 98%,rgba(255,79,25,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,87,21,0) 84%,rgba(255,79,25,0.88) 98%,rgba(255,79,25,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#pagetitle
{
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.title
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 50pt;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Nav menu styling*/

nav
{
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul
{
    list-style: circle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul:after
{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
}

nav ul ul li
{
    float: none;
}

nav ul ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}

nav ul li
{
    width:  25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    background: #FF8566;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

nav ul li:hover
{
    background: #66FFCC;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

nav ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 16pt;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {color: #FF3300;}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PDKVQ/

Comment: Also, the list style in there is incorrect, I was attempting a fix, the list style I am using is list-style: none;

Comment: Why do you using <br> ?

Comment: Just removing the `<br>` tags should resolve your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/PDKVQ/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove the `<br>` from your menu link and add the following line to your css it should work.

At Rule 126 (nav ul li a) add the following:
`line-height: 50px;`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PDKVQ/2/)

Remove the `<br>` from `<li><a href="index.hmtl"><br>HOME</a></li>` and use padding instead:

```
nav ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 16pt;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```